# How to search special character ^ in Vim?

Tags: vim

^ stands for start of a line in Vim. But what if I does want to search for the character ^ itself but not start of lines? I have tried \^ but it seemed not work.

Comment: `\^` is what’s supposed to work with commands like `/` or `s`.  Try it again?

Comment: If you try to search for the 0x1B character, known as Escape and shown as `^[` in vim, you can search for `\e`. (I know this wasn't what you were looking for, but that's what I was looking for when I stumbled upon this page.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you vim session type `/\^`. It works see :)

[image]